# Transferring LSTM weights from Caffe to Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, caffe, lstm

I am trying to transfer LSTM weigts from Caffe to Tensorflow model, but I can't figure out ordering of LSTM weights in Caffe. I managed to export Caffe weights to numpy array.

Comment: Keep an eye out for Tensorflow Open Neural Network Exchange (ONNX) support. Currently Caffe2, PyTorch, and CNTK are supported so unfortunately you cannot use this approach right now with Tensorflow.